# jBPM 6.2 Inclusive Gateway is not waiting for all incoming sequence flows (bug?)

Tags: jbpm, bpmn

I'm currently running into a situation in jBPM 6.2 where the inclusive gateway is not waiting for all the sequence flows to complete. The workflow went past the inclusive gateway after one of the sequence flows reached the inclusive gateway.

How is this possible?

Also, where in the source code is the inclusive gateway logic implemented where it checks whether to go forward in the workflow or not?

**Update: May 13, 2016:**

Digging into the jBPM source code for class `JoinInstanece.java` (https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm/blob/738d191d338dab3e8baceeaf6fe31556b81fe07f/jbpm-flow/src/main/java/org/jbpm/workflow/instance/node/JoinInstance.java#L163) shows that in a split-join inclusive-or gateway pattern, the jBPM engine is try to find all the "active" paths which "can" lead to the `join` gateway. However, whenever there exists 2 or more `xor` diverging gateways in the path to the `join` gateway, jBPM engine will not be able to reach the `join` gateway and hence conclude that there are no "active" paths to it.

More specifically, these lines of code might be causing the problem:

`JoinInstance.java`:

```
if (currentNode instanceof Split && ((Split) currentNode).getType() == Split.TYPE_XOR) {
    if (vistedNodes.contains(startAt.getId())) {
        return false;
    }
```

If the search encounters another "Split" node, then the `visitedNodes` will contain the `startAt`'s id.

Maybe it should be like:

```
if (vistedNodes.contains(startAt.getId()) && currentNode.getId() == startAt.getId()) {
     return false;
}
```